# Cannot fetch from API inside docker container from react app due to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: reactjs, docker, azure-functions

I am running azure functions API inside a docker container and I can access it without problem from postman or e.g. chrome, but I fail to access it from react app. I get an error:

```
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

If I run API locally not in the container I can use `local.settings.json` with:

```
"Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
        "CORS": "*",
        "CORSCredentials": false
    }
```

if I host API in the cloud I can configure CORS in it, but what about when running it in the docker container?

I've been reading different post trying to figure this out but I still fail to find an answer, or an answer that I can understand :/
Is there something I can modify like `local.settings.json` or similar? or do I need to modify `Dockerfile`or something else?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is a browser protection which require an extra header to be resolved . It is a protocol which work between api and browser thus docker can't do anything
So you can change either change your api to send the correct headers explained below .

[CORS in Docker Engine REST Api - DevOps Stack Exchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/cors-in-docker-engine-rest-api#:%7E:text=CORS%20is%20applied%20at%20the%20application%20layer%2C%20not,has%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%20the%20axios%20client.)

Here we will be directly sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the it's value set as '*' this will tell the browser to use the same origin resource .

A different approach would be the use  of using nginx as a proxy with docker
explained below . Here the proxy will change the header .Here you don't have to change your api .

[Solving CORS problem on local development with Docker | by Maximillian Xavier | Medium](https://maximillianxavier.medium.com/solving-cors-problem-on-local-development-with-docker-4d4a25cd8cfe)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add (quote) the relative parts of the links you provided so that your post contains all the required info. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.